# Core Data fetch entities with the same attribute value

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a core data model have 3 attributes, "singerName","albumName","songName".
And there is a table view to display singer string and album string.

For example, I use Michael Jackson to fetch core data. I got 100 results. But there may only have 10 albums each have 10 songs.

My question is how to write NSPredicate to discard the same album without knowing actual album names, only fetch the 10 different albums of Michael Jackson.

`request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"singerName != %@ && ???", @""];`
I want to change ??? to some format to discard the duplicated albumName.

Comment: What are the entities called? Do you have relationships set up? With a correctly designed model this should be easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSArray *uniqueAlbums = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.albumName"];
```

where results is the current fetchedObjects array.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.For performance reason, I use NSDictionaryResultType for the fetch request. So I don't have the fetchedObjects array. Can I just use some kind of NSPredicate setup to do the first fetch?

Comment: As far as I know, it can't be done just setting the NSPredicate. You could try also request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

Comment: Nice! request.returnsDistinctResults = YES. It does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Countries" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSPredicate *objPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cname == %@",objCountries];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:objPredicate];
```